# vivado error when launching MicroBlaze application in sdk

Tags: sdk, fpga, vivado, microblaze

I just try to run a MicroBlaze example  in K-7 board, using vivado 2014.4

And I got an error " MicroBlaze is not being clocked. Check if the Clock input to MicroBlaze and its Bus Interfaces are connected properly"

I already connected differential RTL clock with MicroBlaze as figure.

[Figure: block schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3eF6.png)

and when launching MicroBlaze application in sdk
i got an error shown below:

[Figure: error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKuSn.png)

so many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because(probaly) you have a space character in datapath, from where you load data for sdk. Try saving that to a folder without a space character in the datapath.